# Generating correlated binary and normal variables in Python

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution

I've a list of numbers, say *T*, where each element is sampled from a Normal Distribution.

I'd like to generate another list, say *B*, such that B and T has a particular correlation coefficient *corr* (supplied as an argument), and B consists of purely binary variables.

How can I do such a thing in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by purely binary variables?

Comment: B consists of only 0 and 1s.

Comment: This sounds more like a statistics problem than a Python problem.